# Firing ngSubmit from button in ionic alert

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, alert, ng-submit

I've built an ionic app and I use template driven form in Angular to collect form data and use `ngSubmit` to pass data to `ts.file`. I want to fire `ngSubmit` function through 'No and save data' button in alert but my alert function has nothing to do with my `html.file`. I don't know how to pass data to alert function, either fire `ngSubmit` through alert.

html.file

```
<form #observeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(observeForm.value)" [(observeForm.value)]="tester">
...
  <ion-button margin-top="auto" expand="block" type="submit" routerDirection="backforward">Confirm</ion-button>
</form>
```

ts.file

```
  async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Time Out!',
      message: 'Do you want to add more observe time?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            this.startTimer();
            console.log('Add time Okay');
          }
        },
          {
          text: 'No and save data',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (blah) => {
            this.timer = 0;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get reference by @ViewChild():

```
@ViewChild('observeForm') obsForm: any; // new line

async presentAlertConfirm() {
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  header: 'Time Out!',
  message: 'Do you want to add more observe time?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Yes',
      cssClass: 'secondary',
      handler: () => {
        this.startTimer();
        console.log('Add time Okay');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'No and save data',
      role: 'cancel',
      cssClass: 'secondary',
      handler: (blah) => {
        this.obsForm.onSubmit(); // new line
        this.timer = 0;
      }
    }
  ]
});
await alert.present();
```

}